# Prove if $f$ is increasing then $f'(x) \ge 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a <b$. Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Suppose $f$ is monotonically increasing on $[a,b]$. Show that $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

My attempt: I tried using the Mean Value Theorem, but it doesn't quite seem to work. For example, by the MVT we can conclude that there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(b) - f(a) = f'(c) (b-a)$. Which implies that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$. Now since $f$ is monotonically increasing, $f(b) - f(a) \ge 0$ whenever $b>a$, so $f'(c) \ge 0$. But this only shows for one particular $c \in (a,b)$, and the question asks to show this is true for ALL $x \in (a,b)$. What can I do to complete the proof?

Comment: `My attempt: I tried using the Mean Value Theorem, but it doesn't quite seem to work.` May I ask, then, why you chose to put "*using mean value theorem*" in the title? Maybe MVT is indeed *not* the right way to solve this, and such a title can only discourage better alternative answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $x \in (a,b)$
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\geq0$$

Comment: While this is true, and is indeed the standard way to prove the stated result, it doesn't seem to use the Mean Value Theorem, which is a stated desideratum of the proof.

Comment: Thanks @Shahiba Arora, but is there a proof using MVT?

Comment: No use of MVT at all!!

Comment: @JohnColeman$:$ Mean value theorem is used to prove the converse.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach using MVT will never guarantee the location of $c$ or may not cover all $c\in(a, b)$. Consider for example $f(x) = x^{3}$ in $[-1,1]$. Since $f$ is strictly increasing it follows that the ratio $(f(b) - f(a)) /(b-a) >0$ for any two distinct points $a, b\in[-1,1]$ and thus the corresponding $c$ guaranteed by MVT will always have $f'(c) >0$. This misses the point $c=0$ where derivative vanishes. Thus your proof can not be salvaged. Even isolating such troublesome points like the one given in above example and then showing that derivative vanishes there is [a bit difficult](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1845927/72031).

The proper and much simpler approach is to use the definition of derivative as given in [Sahiba Arora's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2386201/72031).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For a given $x$, there exists $a \le c \le x \le d \le b$ such that $$\frac{f(d)-f(c)}{d-c}=f'(x).$$

Comment: But that isn't what the Mean Value Theorem itself says.

Comment: @JohnColeman The idea is to consider a 'new' function defined on $(c,d)=(x-\delta,x+\eta)$ such that the mean-value theorem gives the desired result.

Comment: How would you finish your proof @Math Lover?

Comment: @user40333 For any given $x \in (a,b)$, we consider the function defined on $[y,z]$, where $x \in (y,z)$, and $a \le y < x < z \le b$ such that $\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}=f'(x)$. Since $f(z) \ge f(y)$, $f'(x) \ge 0$.

Comment: The problem is that unless I am missing something your statement is (in general) false. The converse of the Mean Value Theorem doesn't hold without some additional assumptions. For example $f(x) = x^3$ satisfies $f'(0) = 0$ but $\frac{f(d)-f(c)}{d-c}$ never equals $0$ for any $c,d$ which straddle $0$. Now it might be the case that $f$ increasing is enough to guarantee the result, but if so, that would be a result which is harder to show than the result being proved.

Comment: Nice comment @JohnColeman. I really like you comment. I believe that if the function is monotonically increasing or decreasing then we should be able to find an interval straddling $x$.

Comment: It probably isn't necessary to have equality, if we can assume that $f'(x)$ is continuous. In that case, I see how to tweak your answer into a proof, but continuouty isn't assumed in the problem statement. Perhaps something like Darboux's Theorem is relevant, but then all of a sudden you are talking about a non-trivial proof. This problem is a lot more interesting than I thought at first.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, indeed it is.

Comment: @JohnColeman `it might be the case that f increasing is enough to guarantee the result` Your (counter)example $f(x)=x^3$ *is* increasing, in fact *strictly* increasing.

Comment: Fully agree with @dxiv. The function $f(x) =x^{3}$ is strictly increasing in any interval. This has nothing to do with $x=0$ being a straddle point. Perhaps you are using a different (uncommon/non-popular) definition of monotone function.

Comment: Sorry, I realized my mistake.

Comment: @dxiv You are right of course. When I typed that I was thinking about the derivative of $f$ rather than $f$ itself. Thus this answer is difficult to salvage.

Comment: @dxiv Can we apply this answer for those $x$ where $f'(x)>0$ (or $f'(x) <0$ for monotonically decreasing functions)? I think so. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MathLover No, consider for example $\,f(x)=x^3+x\,$ at $\,x=0\,$. One sufficient condition would be that $\,f\,$ doesn't have an inflection point at the particular $\,x\,$ you are considering, see [A converse proposition to the Mean Value Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339448/a-converse-proposition-to-the-mean-value-theorem) for example (though that and the linked question assume *twice* differentiability).

Comment: Thanks a lot @dxiv.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof can be made to work if $f'$ is continuous. Let $x∈ (a,b)$. Then
for each $n\gg 1$, apply MVT as you have on the interval $(x-\frac1n,x+\frac1n)$  to discover an $x_n$ with $|x_n - x|<1/n$ and $f'(x_n)\geq 0$. Just take $n→∞$ to conclude, using continuity of $f'$.